# Is it possible - using only windows script - to merge a text file and an image?

Tags: scripting, fax, banking

Our FI trading application generates trade confirms which come out as plain text letters. (.txt)

- I need these to be programatically
  overlayed (using only Windows Script)
  onto headed paper and then copied to
  a fax out directory.
- The script will be checking a directory for these files every n minutes.
- I want to keep the dependency count
  down as the script will be running on
  a server so would  like to avoid
  referencing Office libraries if
  possible.

What's the best way to overlay the text file onto the bitmap?

Comment: Sounds like a system worthy of the Daily WTF...

Comment: What would be wrong with creating a COM object (for instance using VB or .NET) which does the job and deploy it on the server?

Comment: Don't please. Preaching to the converted. I am limited by the contraints listed above and also using the award winningly shitty GFI FaxMaker software to trasmit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question but, since I doubt you'll get a pure script based image overlay solution, I suggest the use of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It has a powerful, scriptable command line interface and [handles text-to-image conversions](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/).